# How to make a pause or delay in a Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to write a recursion program (tower of hanoi) and each step must shown in windows form one by one with a little delay but sleep and task.delay didn't work for me :(
here's my code:

```
public void solve(int a,int b,int c,int n,PictureBox[] arr)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        h[c].Push(h[a].Pop());
        print(arr);
        return;
    }

    solve(a, c, b, n - 1,arr);
    h[c].Push(h[a].Pop());
    solve(b, a, c, n - 1, arr);
    print(arr);
    // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep();
}
```

Comment: You can make your method `async` and use a `await Task.Delay(milliseconds)` to set a delay when you need. - Don't use `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with the debugger? This would give you the chance to identify the point where you want to pause. The commented `Sleep` would obviously not be hit between every step.

Answer (score -1):

You said that you program is recursive, so commented Thread.Sleep() won't be hit untlil you reach end of recursion, so better put Thread sleep somewhere else

```
public void solve(int a,int b,int c,int n,PictureBox[] arr)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        h[c].Push(h[a].Pop());
        print(arr);
        return;
    }
    //like here 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep();
    solve(a, c, b, n - 1,arr);
    h[c].Push(h[a].Pop());
    solve(b, a, c, n - 1, arr);
    print(arr);        
}
```